# How to run same test case for four differant environments in selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

On my project i have 4 different environment.
Dev,stag,uat and prod.
So i need to run a test case for all four environments as a one test case.

Only the change to the code will be web driver URL.

So below is my `AssemblyInitialize` and in here im trying open the webdriver with two of my environments.
but it is not going to work.

```
 [AssemblyInitialize]
        public static void setupDriver(TestContext TestContext)
        {
            string[] array = new string[2];
            array[0] = URL1;
            array[1] = URL2;
            foreach (var item in array)
            {


            Driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverFilePath);
            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(item);
            Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            SetupElm elm = new SetupElm();
            elm.IdentityServer.Click();


            Extent = new ExtentReports(ExtentHTMLReportPath, true);


            }
```

Comment: Try virtual environment, it will work. Each virtual environment handles one instance of browser to test one particular environment under test.

Comment: You mean something like virtual machine ,VM ware ...etc

Comment: yes, exactly what i meant

Comment: Do the different environments differ wildly in configuration? I imagine you should be able to use variables for all the server-specific configuration and then fill these variables at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

As always, there's numerous ways to do this. Here are just two example:

### Java

If you use Java, you can use [System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) to pass configuration data like the target URL into your test.

#### Example

Instead of this:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(...);
driver.get("http://dev/app/...");
```

Use this:

```
String env = System.getProperty("target.env");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(...);
driver.get(env);
```

This allows you to specify a value for `target.env` dynamicaly at runtime.

How you specify the value when executing tests depends on how you run them. If you start your tests from Eclipse, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862391/how-to-pass-the-d-system-properties-while-testing-on-eclipse) for example.

If you run your tests through the command line, just add the `-D` switch and specify the value accordingly:

```
java -jar mytests.jar -Dtarget.env=http://prod/app/...
```

### .NET

In .NET the simplest way to do this is passing that information via an [environment variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6(v=vs.110).aspx).

#### Example

Instead of this:

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver(...);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://dev/app/...");
```

Use this:

```
var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("targetenv");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(...);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(env);
```

When running the tests, just make sure that you set the environment variable `targetenv` to the desired URL. You can easily do this in the command line, as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description , But i think i didnt get the exact answer im looking for so that i will update my question.